# How to insert queryset results in a table with foreign key in django

Tags: python, twitter, django-models

I have 2 tables : RawTweet and PertinentTweet, PertinentTweet has a foreign key which references tweetID in Rawtweet. And I want to select some tweets in RawTweet and store them in PertinentTweet. I'm using queryset to do that.

My 2 classes :

```
class RawTweet(models.Model):
    tweetID = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length = 200, blank=True)
    pseudo = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    userLocation = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    tweetLocation = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/', blank=True)
    isretweeted = models.NullBooleanField()
    hashtags = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    score=models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pseudo+' le ' + self.date
    def getUrl(self):
        return ("https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}".format(self.pseudo,self.tweetID))


class PertinentTweet(models.Model):
    rawTweetID=models.ForeignKey(RawTweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, default=0)
```

Here the part of my views.py where I'm using the queryset:

```
        potentialTweets=RawTweet.objects.filter(score__gte=7)
        for item in potentialTweets:
            goodTweet = PertinentTweet()
            goodTweet.rawTweetID = item.tweetID
            goodTweet.save()
```

When I lunch my application I have this error :

ValueError at /
Cannot assign "?": "PertinentTweet.rawTweetID" must be a "RawTweet" instance.

It looks like the queryset object "potentialTweets" isn't a list of  RawTweet objects... I know it must be because I define a foreign key in PertinentTweet to reference tweet in RawTweet. And I would like to keep the link with my two tables. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would avoid the error:

```
goodTweet.rawTweetID = item
```

Although, I'm not sure if I understand your question.

In your code, `potentialTweets` is indeed a query set of `RawTweet` objects.
And `item.tweetID` is just a field of `RawTweet`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! Yes potentialTweets contains RawTweet objects and item.tweetID is a field of RawTweet. I just want to keep a field tweetID (of RawTweet) in field rawTweetID (of PertinentTweet) it is why I put  goodTweet.rawTweetID = item.tweetID. I'm trying to use your advice and I will say you if it works. Thks

Comment: It doesn't work. I think if you say goodTweet.rawTweetID = item it means storing the all fiel of item in a single field. But I would like to keep only the tweetID field. When I changed goodTweet.rawTweetID = item.tweetID to goodTweet.rawTweetID = item to goodTweet.rawTweetID = item like ypu suggest

Comment: If you only want to keep `item.tweetID`, then you don't need a ForeignKey to `RawTweet`. You could just use a BigIntegerField in `PertinentTweet`.

Comment: Oh sorry it works Thank you :) It was a mistake in somewhere in my script and I fixed It. Is it possible to keep in table PertinentTweet the field tweetID ? Thank you !

Comment: Ok but I would like to keep the link with the two tables. I mean when I delete a tweet in RawTweet and if I have a tweet with the same tweetID field in PertinentTweet  I would like to delete it automatically.

Comment: In that case, a ForeignKey sounds like a good option (using `on_delete=models.CASCADE` as you are doing). If you don't want to use a foreign key, you could achieve a similar result by overriding the `delete` method of the model.